# Python using multiple terms to find

Tags: python, list

How do I find multiple keywords from textsource in this example? I would like to find aaa OR bbb OR ccc.

```
if str(textsource).find("aaa") == -1:
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Use a regular expression:

```
import re

if not re.search("aaa|bbb|ccc", str(textsource)):
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple use of [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) would work:

```py
if any(sub in string for sub in subs):
```

Or more accurately for your case:

```py
if not any(sub in textsource for sub in ("aaa", "bbb", "ccc")):
```

Also possible with [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all):

```py
if all(sub not in textsource for sub in ("aaa", "bbb", "ccc")):
```

Comment: Isn't `not any(...)` generally preferred over `all(not ...)`?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica well after some time going over it, I couldn't think of any advantage to either way. It seems they will both do exactly the same and perform the same amount of "steps". What am I missing? Still updated my answer, thanks

Comment: The big reason is that it's easier to think about (IMO). However, if you're counting "steps" to micro-optimize, I think `not any` is still better, as then it only does a single `not` rather than a `not` for each element.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I'm not very familiar with the under-the-hood implementation details of Python, but I believe `x not in y` is a bit different than `not x in y` as it is not necessarily performs another `not` operation. It is basically the same as `in` with the inverse output. Do you know if this is true?

Comment: I don't know. However, the simplicity argument is still there.

Comment: I believe it's a matter of taste. Depends on how it's easier to think of the logic. For me I thought of it as "check that all strings are not present"...

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> textsource
'aaabbbccc'
```

Finding the index of multiple search terms:

```
>>> [textsource.find(kw) for kw in ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd"]]
[0, 3, 6, -1]
```

Converting those results to booleans indicating "found" or "not found":

```
>>> [textsource.find(kw) == -1 for kw in ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd"]]
[False, False, False, True]
```

Returning a single boolean indicating if any one of the multiple search terms was not found.

```
>>> any(textsource.find(kw) == -1 for kw in ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd"])
True
```

For comparisons sake, here's the result when all of the search terms are found:

```
>>> [textsource.find(kw) == -1 for kw in ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]]
[False, False, False]
>>> any(textsource.find(kw) == -1 for kw in ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"])
False
```

Comment: Ouch. Hurts seeing a list comprehension inside `any(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
textsource = 'aaa bbb ccc ddd'
kw_list = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
for word in kw_list:
    if textsource.find(word) != -1:
        print('keyword:'+ word + ' found at pos:'+ str(textsource.find(word)))
    else:
        print('keyword:'+ word + ' not found in the textsource')
```

Comment: Code-only answers are considered low quality: make sure to provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem.
It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post. See also Explaining entirely code-based answers: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers